# Where's the source of mysqlclient.lib?

Tags: c, mysql, libmysql

I have a C++ application which connects to a MySQL server.
It all works fine.

Currently it uses libmysql.dll.
At build time I link to libmysql.lib.

As far as I understand I can link to mysqlclient.lib instead and get rid of the dependency of libmysql.dll, i.e have the functionality embedded within my exe.

My question is: **Where can I find the source to build mysqlclient.lib** ?

When debugging the app when it's linked to mysqlclient.lib and stepping into mysql_library_init() for example the debugger (VC++ 2008) asks for the file "f:\build\mysql-5.0.67-winbuild\mysql-community-nt-5.0.67-build\libmysql\libmysql.c".

Note: libmysql.lib & mysqlclient.lib are included in the installation of MySQL.

Comment: Someone please tell me why down-vote this question. Written very clearly, and very programming-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, it's a part of the MySQL source code: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads

Comment: Hi and thanks! I tried the package mysql-noinstall-5.1.49-win32.zip (115MB) yet again no source files except for headers. Any idea?

Comment: You've chosen the wrong package. The correct link is: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=391854

Comment: Tip: There on https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ in the "Select operating system" picker select "Source code".